# How to use permission-based authorization for different controllers in .NET 6

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I want to implement permission based authorization in different controllers

I have implemented permission-based authorization for the weather forecast screen. Now, if I want to create a set of permissions for a different controller, such as the brand controller, how do I do that, and how do I handle that permission while authorizing.
I'm new to .NET.

```
[HasPermission(Permission.ViewForecast)]
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }

public class HasPermission : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public HasPermission(string permission): base(policy:permission)
    {
        
    }
}
```

These are the permissions which I have created

```
public class Permission
{
    public const string CreateForecast = "Permission.WeatherForecast.Create";
    public const string ViewForecast = "Permission.WeatherForecast.Read";
    public const string UpdateForecast = "Permission.WeatherForecast.Update";
    public const string DeleteForecast = "Permission.WeatherForecast.Delete";
}
```

This is the permission handler

```
public class PermissionAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<PermissionRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, PermissionRequirement requirement)
    {
        var permissions = context.User.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == CustomClaims.permissions)
                                                .Select(x => x.Value).ToHashSet();           
        if (permissions.Contains(requirement.Permission))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    
}
```